# The "Exception in Application start method" error occurred when running this JavaFX project

Tags: javafx

This project uses the following libraries, Java version 11, and the IDE is the latest community version of IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]

The following is the project code:

```
package com.example.demo;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import jfxtras.styles.jmetro.JMetro;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        JMetro jMetro = new JMetro();
//        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 320, 240);
        jMetro.setScene(scene);
        Button button = new Button("Click me!");
        VBox root = (VBox) scene.getRoot();
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

This is the error message during program runtime:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.recalculateRelativeSizeProperties(Ljavafx/scene/Node;Ljavafx/scene/text/Font;)V
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.set(Labeled.java:375)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.set(Labeled.java:347)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.applyStyle(StyleableObjectProperty.java:68)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.applyStyle(Labeled.java:361)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.applyStyle(Labeled.java:347)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.transitionToState(CssStyleHelper.java:787)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.doProcessCSS(Node.java:9647)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.access$900(Node.java:398)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.doProcessCSS(Node.java:471)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSSImpl(NodeHelper.java:192)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:93)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.superProcessCSS(ParentHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1366)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.superProcessCSS(ControlHelper.java:55)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1397)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9529)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:569)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1745)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1086)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1174)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:26)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.demo.HelloApplication
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfxtras/jmetro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmetro</artifactId>
            <version>11.6.16</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo/com.example.demo.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

IDEA VERSION:

[image]

At first, the computer's runtime environment was Java version 19. Later, it was thought that the Java version was too high, so the Java version was changed to 11. However, the program still threw an error when running.

Comment: You have weird versioning problems. Look at your first screenshot. Both `javafx.base:win` and `javafx.graphics:win` are version `11.0.2`, but the other JavaFX dependencies with the `win` classifier are version `17.0.2`. That is likely where your problem is coming from. Though I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Also, it's been my experience that modular stack frames in a stack trace will show the module version unless the module is part of the run-time image. I might be wrong about that. But your stack trace doesn't show the JavaFX module versions. Do you happen to have a JDK distribution that includes JavaFX (e.g., BellSoft Liberica or Azul Zulu)? If yes, then you do not need to, nor should you, define JavaFX dependencies in your POM.